# Decompiling MCP error (version 9.18) returns 'Decompile Failed' 1

Tags: java, minecraft

I have a 64-bit System and use the 64-bit Java version.

I'd like to do a minecraft mod with the mcp. But always when I'm decompiling it, I get an error

Does anyone know how to fix this error? :D

```
== MCP 9.18 (data: 9.18, client: 1.8.8, server: 1.8.8) ==
"scalac" is not found on the PATH.  Scala files will not be recompiled
# found ff, ff patches, srgs, name csvs, doc csvs, param csvs, astyle, astyle co
nfig, rg, ss
== Decompiling client using fernflower ==
> Creating SRGs
> Applying SpecialSource
> Applying MCInjector
> Creating renamed srg
> Filtering classes
> Decompiling
'"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java" -Xmx2G runtime\bin\fernflower.jar
 -din=1 -rbr=1 -dgs=1 -asc=1 -rsy=1 -iec=1 -jvn=1 -log=WARN "-e=jars\libraries\n
et/java/jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/lwjgl/lwjgl
\lwjgl-platform\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl-platform-2.9.4-nightly-20150209-nat
ives-windows.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/ibm/icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\icu4j-co
re-mojang-51.2.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\tv/twitch\twitch-external-platform\4.5\tw
itch-external-platform-4.5-natives-windows-64.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache
/httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\httpcore-4.3.2.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache
/logging/log4j\log4j-api\2.0-beta9\log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\o
rg/apache/commons\commons-lang3\3.3.2\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar" "-e=jars\librarie
s\net/java/dev/jna\jna\3.4.0\jna-3.4.0.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\lib
raryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\net/sf/
jopt-simple\jopt-simple\4.6\jopt-simple-4.6.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/google/g
uava\guava\17.0\guava-17.0.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\oshi-project\oshi-core\1.1\os
hi-core-1.1.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.3\h
ttpclient-4.3.3.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/commons\commons-compress\1.8.
1\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\net/java/dev/jna\platform\3.4.0
\platform-3.4.0.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codec
jorbis-20101023.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\sound
system-20120107.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\2010082
4\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/lwjgl/lwjgl\lwjgl_util
\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar" "-e=jars\librarie
s\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.9\commons-codec-1.9.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\net/
java/jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\commons-logging\co
mmons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/lwjgl/lwjg
l\lwjgl\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar" "-e=jars\librar
ies\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/mojang\
realms\1.7.39\realms-1.7.39.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/mojang\authlib\1.5.21\au
thlib-1.5.21.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/google/code/gson\gson\2.2.4\gson-2.2.4.
jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/mojang\netty\1.6\netty-1.6.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\t
v/twitch\twitch\6.5\twitch-6.5.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\codecwav\20
101023\codecwav-20101023.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\tv/twitch\twitch-platform\6.5\t
witch-platform-6.5-natives-windows-64.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\net/java/jinput\ji
nput-platform\2.0.5\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar" "-e=jars\librarie
s\org/apache/logging/log4j\log4j-core\2.0-beta9\log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar" "-e=ja
rs\libraries\io/netty\netty-all\4.0.23.Final\netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar" temp/mi
necraft_ff_in.jar temp\src\minecraft' failed : 1
Decompile failed
Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .
```

Comment: Install the Scala compiler and add it to your path.

Comment: To which path i have to add it?

Comment: It's the Windows system path. See here for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows

Comment: Are you sure that  the error is caused by "scalac not found"?

Comment: The Scala compiler being missing wouldn't cause this. I'd need to see the FernFlower output to know why it's failing. Though, why are you trying to use MCP directly? Forge's tools are much easier to use and are probably what you intended to use, not MCP directly. Not to mention that 1.8.8 is a pretty old version at this point. (You can get Forge at https://files.minecraftforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I know that the 1.8.8 is an old version but I like this version more than the 1.9 or higher. I cleaned up the folder where the MCP stuff were in and after trying again it worked. So the problem is fixes.

Answer (score -1):

In the MCP folder, open the `conf` folder and then open `mcp.cfg` with a text editor of your choice. Then, find this line (near the bottom)

`CmdFernflower = %s -jar %s -din=1 -rbr=0 -dgs=1 -asc=1 -log=WARN {indir} {outdir}`

and replace it with this:

`CmdFernflower = %s -Xmx2G -jar %s -din=1 -rbr=0 -dgs=1 -asc=1 -log=WARN {indir} {outdir}`

(You may need to change other lines also adding -Xmx2G before -jar but it doesn't seem to be needed from my experience).

This will run the decompiler with additional RAM which should fix this problem.